# curious with zend framework 2

Tags: zend-framework2

Hello i am new to this framework and i am getting this error when following the tutorial.

Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend\ModuleManager\Exception\RuntimeException' with message 'Module (Album) could not be initialized.' in C:\website\zend\vendor\ZF2\library\Zend\ModuleManager\ModuleManager.php on line 175

here is the code that i believe there is a mistake

```
<?php
return array(
    // This should be an array of module namespaces used in the application.
    'modules' => array(
        'Application',
        'Album',    // <-- Add this line to make new module available              
    ),

    // These are various options for the listeners attached to the ModuleManager
    'module_listener_options' => array(
        // This should be an array of paths in which modules reside.
        // If a string key is provided, the listener will consider that a module
        // namespace, the value of that key the specific path to that module's
        // Module class.
        'module_paths' => array(
            './module',
            './vendor',
        ),

        // An array of paths from which to glob configuration files after
        // modules are loaded. These effectively override configuration
        // provided by modules themselves. Paths may use GLOB_BRACE notation.
        'config_glob_paths' => array(
            'config/autoload/{,*.}{global,local}.php',
        ),

        // Whether or not to enable a configuration cache.
        // If enabled, the merged configuration will be cached and used in
        // subsequent requests.
        //'config_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the configuration cache file name.
        //'config_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // Whether or not to enable a module class map cache.
        // If enabled, creates a module class map cache which will be used
        // by in future requests, to reduce the autoloading process.
        //'module_map_cache_enabled' => $booleanValue,

        // The key used to create the class map cache file name.
        //'module_map_cache_key' => $stringKey,

        // The path in which to cache merged configuration.
        //'cache_dir' => $stringPath,

        // Whether or not to enable modules dependency checking.
        // Enabled by default, prevents usage of modules that depend on other modules
        // that weren't loaded.
        // 'check_dependencies' => true,
    ),

    // Used to create an own service manager. May contain one or more child arrays.
    //'service_listener_options' => array(
    //     array(
    //         'service_manager' => $stringServiceManagerName,
    //         'config_key'      => $stringConfigKey,
    //         'interface'       => $stringOptionalInterface,
    //         'method'          => $stringRequiredMethodName,
    //     ),
    // )

   // Initial configuration with which to seed the ServiceManager.
   // Should be compatible with Zend\ServiceManager\Config.
   // 'service_manager' => array(),
);
```

Comment: Hello! Welcome to stackoverflow! Your application.config.php seems ok, but its not enough to understand why modulemanager couldn't load the album module. Can you add the `Module.php` and `module.config.php` contents to question?

Comment: Sounds like you did not fully follow the tutorial. Did you actually install the `Album` module along with all of the associated files?

Answer (score -1):

Like @foozy said, if you can post more of the code, that would be a big help. It could be a number of things, such as the name you've specified in module.config.php is different from the Module directory or namespace, or a variety of things.